# MS Word has blocked my document into some weird mode, how can I fix this?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

[Suddenly get stuck into this mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RdGy.jpg)

After hours of working on a doc, I've CMD+TAB'ed out of the doc and suddenly come back to this. It's happened before and after some clicking around, I went to Review > Protect Document (which was enabled somehow) and that fixed.

However, now it won't work. I desperately need help. I'm not sure even what mode this is, it shows super wide pages, can't select text properly.

Comment: Try the buttons at the bottom (the one next to "Focus") near the zoom slider...

Comment: Perhaps anything on the View tab? like Draft view maybe?

Comment: No, I've tried everything under that tab as well.

Comment: If you didn't mean to be in Review mode, just press the Accept (or Accept All) button shown and go back to normal edit mode.